# \LaTeX macro: "Font shape `OT1/LatinModernSans(0)/m/n' undefined"

Tags: beamer, luatex, fontspec, latin-modern

I tried compiling the following example using LuaLaTeX (LuaTeX v0.76/TeX Live 2013):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\title{\LaTeX}

\begin{document}

\frame{Test}

\end{document}
```

However, I get a font warning about Latin Modern Sans in the console/in the log file:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+LatinModernSans(0) on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file OT1LatinModernSans(0).fd. on input line 15.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/LatinModernSans(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 15.
```

I don't understand why I get this warning. If I do one of the following, it disappears:

- Stop using `\LaTeX` in the `\title`
- Remove the `\usetheme` line (presumably because the title is not used then)
- Remove the line `\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}`; I don't understand this, doesn't LuaTeX load Latin Modern as a default anyway? Or is it Computer Modern?

I see that the problem seems to be the `\LaTeX` macro. If I use the hologo package with `\hologo{LaTeX}`, there is no warning either, but I'd like to understand why this is causing problems and if there's some deeper problem.

Console output:

```
$ lualatex test.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013121407 (rev 4627) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 33 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamer.cls
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasercs.sty)
Document Class: beamer 2012/10/15 development version 3.24 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 24853e6b98cf)

...

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/LatinModernSans(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 15.

...

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

...
```

Comment: I don't get the complaint with TeX Live 2014 (updated yesterday) but I would still add `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` to stop `beamer` trying to define fonts itself.

Comment: *doesn't LuaTeX load Latin Modern as a default anyway? Or is it Computer Modern?* -- The latter: by default the Luatex formats behave like Pdftex and load only CM in the Type1 version. *Fontspec*, however, loads the LM fonts with a set of definitions for different optical sizes. (See e.g. ``cat $(kpsewhich eu2lmr.fd)``.) There is really no point in defining the font yourself again *after* loading Fontspec.

Comment: @cfr I still get the warning with \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}, but if there's no issue in TeX Live 2014, I guess I'll just wait for that (not in my distribution's repositories yet) to ease my worries.

Comment: @phg So just by saying `\usepackage{fontspec}`, Latin Modern is set as the default font? I didn't find that anywhere in the documentation, but that would be nice.

I thought `\setmainfont` etc. just select the default font and didn't think of it as a "font definition". So there is a difference between just loading `fontspec` and saying `\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}`?

Comment: I don't think there's a difference. @phg just said that there 'is really no point' in defining it again. It is a font definition in a limited sense i.e. you are defining the sans font to be so-and-so. It is definitely *not* a font definition in the sense that LaTeX (not Lua/XeLaTeX) uses 'font definition's!

Comment: @Socob: *I thought \setmainfont etc. just select the default font and didn't think of it as a "font definition"* -- Well, in order to *use* the font above all you need to *define* it. So if you have printed text in your document then the statement will result in font definitions. *So there is a difference between just loading fontspec and saying ``\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}?``* -- Possibly. Fontspec’s definitions for LM (see the the file I cited earlier) may differ from a dynamic definition using the ``\setfoofont`` macros.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a not reproducible problem (see comments)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the warning disappeared if you get rid of `\LaTeX` from some title, means that the theme has been created either with an old definition of that command, or thet the definition is incompatible with `LuaLaTeX`.

In facts "someone" specified that some text had to be typeset with the standard Old TeX encoding OT!; normally the default encoding for open type fonts used by `Luatex` is EU2; since you did not specify any encoding, that old encoding is specified by the theme and it should be necessary to correct the theme (or `beamer` itself? I doubt it, but who knows...)

Package `xpatch` could be used to locally patch some existing commands without actually putting one’s hands inside packages.